# why i can't use projects of netbeans without netbeans?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans

I've cloned a NetBeans made project from git to my IntelliJ and not the IntelliJ throws this error and doesn't run the programme.

```
Error:(126, 59) java: package org.netbeans.lib.awtextra does not exist
```

I've also searched for maven dependency of that as well, but IntelliJ says that the dependency isn't valid too.

to make the story short, I was basically wondering for an easy way to use NetBeans project on IntelliJ

thank you in advance :)

Comment: [1] This may help: [How do I open a NetBeans project in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/netbeans.html#how-do-i-open-a-netbeans-project). If you have already followed those instructions to import your project from NetBeans into Intellij IDEA and still have problems, update your question to provide more details of exactly what you did. [2] Does your NetBeans project use any special NetBeans plugins?